# How to know that a select element has no items ( options data )?

Tags: jquery

There is a select element. On page load it has no data ( options ). How to know that it has no data ( options ) ?

Comment: Try: `jQuery(yourSelector).is(":empty") ` , http://jsfiddle.net/4c3dk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of options like this:

```
var num = $('#your_select').children('option').length;
if(num < 1){
    // no option
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7RW4t/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select#selectid option').length
```

Check using this.. If zero no option tag is present..

Answer (score 1):

check the length of children

```
$('select').children().length
```

if this return 0, then it won't have children.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/xTTKq/)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if($('yourselector').length==0){
//nothing selected
}else{
//there is something selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DBgS5/)

```
console.log($('select > option').length === 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code.

<select id="opt">
<option></option>
</select>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var chckopt = document.getElementById("opt").value;
if(chckopt == "")
alert("empty");
});
</script>
Hope this is what you were asking for.
```